# Problem while trying to create web service with symfony

Tags: sql, json, symfony, doctrine-orm

so I'm building a mobile/web app with symfony framework for the web side and codenamone for the mobile side. I encountered an error while trying to run my add function : " Expected value of type Entity for association field "PBundle\Entity\Projet#$Partenaire", got "string" instead."

I have actually two tables in my database that are related: Projet and Partenaire. Projet got a foreign key which is referencing the id of Partenaire . 
Here is my code :

```
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $projets = new Projet();
        $projets->setNomProjet($request->get('nomProjet'));
        $projets->setDescription($request->get('description'));
        $projets->setDate($request->get('date'));
        $projets->setNombreParticipant($request->get('nombreParticipant'));
        $projets->setPartenaire($request->get('Partenaire'));
        $em->persist($projets);
        $em->flush();
        $serializer = new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()]);
        $formatted = $serializer->normalize($projets);
        return new JsonResponse($formatted);
    }
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line: `$projets->setPartenaire($request->get('Partenaire'));`
You need to get Partenaire by `id` at first and then to set it here (not an `id` of entity).

Something like this:

```
$partnaireRepo = $em->getRepository(Entity\Partenaire::class);
$partenaire = $partnaireRepo->find($request->get('Partenaire'));
if ($partenaire) {
    $projets->setPartenaire($partenaire);
}
```

This should work.

Comment: I tried to change it like that and got this error ( Class 'PBundle\Controller\Partenaire' does not exist) 
 then I tried to change this line        
 $partnaireRepo = $em->getRepository('PBundle:Partenaire'); 
and got another error  ( errorError: Call to a member function format() on string )

Comment: try `$em->getRepository(Entity\Partenaire::class)` or where this Entity class file?